# Unique Key Generation Logic

Tags: php, python, mysql

I am planning to build, for lack of a better term, a multi user Customer Relationship Manager (CRM) and I want to create a unique identifier that is easy to transmit in email, via text, and verbally to other team members.

For Example:

I upload my list of 100 customers and John Smith and his phone number are included in that list. Upon upload, I want to generate a hidden fingerprint / unique identifier for John Smith in the database, and then propagate a 12 digit number that can be shared publicly.

In my mind like this - john smith + ph: 5557898095 = fingerprint: 7e013d7962800374e6e67dd502f2d7c0 displays to end user id number: 103457843983

My question is - what method or process should I use to take the name and phone number, generate a hidden key, and then translate to a displayable key that is linked to the hidden one?

I hope this clear. I mainly want to use the right logic process.

Comment: Do you really want to base the ID on the phone number?  What if the customer's phone number changes?

Comment: Why do you need this? Seems like a lot of effort to go to when a simple integer id (as auto-generated by mysql) would server - much more human readable that any arbitrary 12 digit number, and better as a database index key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what your problem really is, but I'll try.

It seems like you mean something like this:

A SQL table which saves the public and private ID (and maybe other things).

You can generate a key like this:

```
$chars = '0123456789abcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

function generateKey($length, $charsLength = 10) {
    global $chars;
    
    $key = '';

    for($i=0;$i<$length;++$i) {
        $key .= $chars[rand(0, $charsLength - 1)];
    }
    
    return $key;
}

$keyPublic = generateKey(10); // Public key with length 10

// Now check if the key already exist
while(mysql_num_rows(mysql_select('SELECT publicKey FROM keys WHERE publicKey = \''.$keyPublic.'\')) === 1) {
    $keyPublic = generateKey(10);
}

$keyPrivate = generateKey(10, 36); // Private key with length 10

// Now check if the key already exist
while(mysql_num_rows(mysql_select('SELECT privateKey FROM keys WHERE privateKey = \''.$keyPrivate.'\')) === 1) {
    $keyPrivate = generateKey(10, 36);
}
```

In this example there are two keys generated and it is checked if the keys already exist. (in the example in the table "keys").

Comment: Thank you - this gives me the right direction for what I need to accomplish :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [crc32('fingerprint')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) for the end user id number:

```
<?php 
  echo printf("%u", crc32('7e013d7962800374e6e67dd502f2d7c0')); //226407465310
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your real ID is the auto_incremented field in your customer table, then just have a second table that maps your public ID to the real ID.

Assuming you're using some sort of hashing algorithm to generate your public ID, it'd be a simple process to do a lookup on that table when you create a new user to detect a clash with an existing user, then regenerate a new ID until there's no clash (e.g. include system time as part of your hash input, then just keep regenerating until you find a unique ID)

Comment: Also very helpful, thank you. I know my question was somewhat vague, but between you and @user1150525 I have what I need to complete my spec doc for now. Thanks!